# getting this to repeat using a while loop. credit card validation

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm almost done with this project for my intro to java programming class. It's a credit card validation program. I know I'm super close to being done. All I need to do is to ask the user if he would like to enter another card number after the first one. 
Normally the program says please enter your card number
*user inputs card number*
program determines if visa, mastercard etc... then determines if valid.
Simple enough.but I need to alter it to say

"please enter a card number"

*user inputs card number*

"would you like to input another card number?"

*user inputs yes or no*

If it's yes then the method reruns and gets another number then proceeds to do so until the user says no.
After the user says no, the program determines if the cards are visa, mastercards, etc... and if they are valid.

My code is posted below. I am pretty sure I need a while loop but I'm not quite sure how to set it up. The code below is just the getcardnumber method.

TLDR;
How do i get this to repeat until the user stops inputting card numbers?

```
public static String getCardNumber() {
        String cardNumber;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the credit card number: ");
        cardNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
        //remove spaces from cardNumber
        cardNumber = cardNumber.replace(" ", "");
        while (!isAllDigits(cardNumber)) {
            System.out.println("The credit card number must contain only the"
                    + " digits 0-9; please re-enter: ");
            cardNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
            //remove spaces from cardNumber
            cardNumber = cardNumber.replace(" ", "");
        }
        //a number containing only digits has been entered
        return cardNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    boolean b = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Number 2: ");
        Item2 item2 = new Item2();
        System.out.println("Please enter the credit card number: ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(checkNumber(keyboard.nextLine(), keyboard));

        System.out.println("Would you like to input another card number? 1=Yes; 2=No");
        int decision = Input.nextInt();

        if (decision == 1){
            b = false;
        }else if (decision == 2){
            b = true;
        }
    }while(b == false);
}

public static String checkNumber(String cardNumber, Scanner keyboard) {
    //remove spaces from cardNumber
    cardNumber = cardNumber.replace(" ", "");
    while (!isAllDigits(cardNumber)) {
        System.out.println("The credit card number must contain only the"
                + " digits 0-9; please re-enter: ");
        cardNumber = keyboard.nextLine();
        //remove spaces from cardNumber
        cardNumber = cardNumber.replace(" ", "");
    }
    //a number containing only digits has been entered
    return cardNumber;
}
```